# Transform Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, transform, indexof

Hey there i am using this little jquery:

```
$("area.imagefield[data-name='" + searchText + "']").each(function() {
```

to check if the value of the attribute "data-name" matches exactly the variable "searchText".

But i need to check if the value of the attribute "data-name" is index of the variable "searchText", so using the

```
.indexOf
```

What i tried:

```
$("area.imagefield[data-name=]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-name").indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
        console.log("match");
    } else {
        console.log("no match");
    }
```

But there is no log in the console... :/ any idea´s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code looks good except one typo.
Remove the equal sign after `data-name` otherwise it's an invalid css selector:
So `area.imagefield[data-name=]` should be `area.imagefield[data-name]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$("#imagefieldID").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-name").indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
        console.log("match");
    } else {
        console.log("no match");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery data()**

Is the normal way of working with`data` attributes in jQuery, and probably what you would want to use.

```
$('area.imagefield').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).data('name')===searchText) {
        console.log('match '+i);
    } else { console.log('no match '+i); }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/mau93/